# Trigonometric Idenities for $\sin^5(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

First off, not going to lie, this is for an assignment.

Basically, we're given the integral $$\int \sin^5(x)\,dx$$ and rewritten form of $$\int [A \sin(x) + B \sin (x) \cos^2 (x)+C\sin(x)\cos^4(x)]\,dx$$ using certain trigonometric Identities. We're required to find the values of $A$, $B$ and $C$. Now for the life of me I can't find a set of transformations that will give me that transformation. The power reducing formula gets me to $$\int 
(5/8)\sin X - (5/16)\sin(3X) + (1/16)\sin(5X) $$
and then I can use the multiple angles identity on $\sin(3x)$ and $\sin(5x)$, and then I use the power Identities again on the resultant and I just seem to keep going in circles, unable to get the transformation asked for and answer the question.

Please send help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy. Notice that

$$\sin^5 x = \sin x \sin^4 x = \sin x (1- \cos^2 x)^2 = \sin x (1 - 2 \cos ^2 x + \cos^4 x) ,$$

so $A = 1, \ B = -2, \ C = 1$.

Integration, then, is easy, because

$$\int \sin x \cos^n x \ \Bbb d x = - \int (\cos x)' \cos^n x \ \Bbb d x = \frac {\cos^{n+1} x} {n + 1} .$$

Comment: I'm not going to lie
The amount of ways of approaching a problem in calculus really gets to me
Anyway, thanks

Comment: @EurekaKN We are not going to lie, but this solution is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
You want to find values for $A,B$ and $C$ such that, *for all* $x$, we have that $$\sin^5(x)=A\sin x+B\sin x\cos^2x+C\sin x\cos^4x.$$ So try to plug there some specific values, such as $x=\tfrac\pi2$, to solve for $A,B$ and $C$.